# View PayPal history prior to 2011

Tags: paypal

I am trying to see a transaction I made years ago. The PayPal transactions only went up to 2011. Is there anyway to see further than that or is that lost forever?

Comment: If you go to "download history" (click on the Statements down arrow and select "download"), you can get this data 2 years at a time. I never noticed until now that the online history now stops at 11/20/2011 (3 year limit), that must be something new.